# McNemar test in R - sparse data

Tags: r, contingency

I'm attempting to run a good sized dataset through R, using the McNemar test to determine whether I have a difference in the proportion of objects detected by one method over another on paired samples. I've noticed that the test works fine when I have a 2x2 table of

```
   test1
   y    n
y  34   2
n  12   16
```

but if I try and run something more like:

```
34   0
12   0
```

it errors telling me that ''x' and 'y' must have the same number of levels (minimum 2)'.

I should clarify, that I've tried converting wide data to a 2x2 matrix using the table function on my wide data set, where rather than appearing as above, it negates the final column, giving me.

```
test1
    y
y  34
n  12
```

I've also run mcnemar.test using the factor object option, which gives me the same error, so I'm assuming that it does something similar. I'm wondering whether there is either a way to force the table function to generate the 2nd column despite their being no observations which would fall under either of those categories, or whether there would be a way to make the test overlook this missing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there's a better way to do this, but you can force R to construct a sparse contingency table by ensuring that the tabulated factors have the same `levels` attribute and that there are exactly 2 distinct levels specified.

```
# Example data
x1 <- c(rep("y", 34), rep("n", 12))
x2 <- rep("n", 46)

# Set levels explicitly
x1 <- factor(x1, levels = c("y", "n"))
x2 <- factor(x2, levels = c("y", "n"))

table(x1, x2)
#    x2
# x1   y  n
#   y  0 34
#   n  0 12

mcnemar.test(table(x1, x2))
#
#  McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction
#
# data:   table(x1, x2)
# McNemar's chi-squared = 32.0294, df = 1, p-value = 1.519e-08
```